# Who exactly is "you" here?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021), Aunt May stabs Norman with a green-colored syringe:

> GOBLIN: It didn't work. Norman was right. He got it from **you**,
> that pathetic sickness.

Who exactly is "you" here?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Jack Vader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Goblin was looking directly at May when he said that. And it makes sense -- taking into account what he said just a few seconds earlier -- that he was referring to her, since the "pathetic sickness" he apparently had in mind was morality.

> GREEN GOBLIN: (growling) **Your weakness, Peter, is morality. It's choking you! Can you feel it?!**
>
> [May quickly runs towards Osborn and stabs him in the neck with the injector meant to cure him. After letting out a ghastly squawk, he rips it out and throws it to the ground. The antidote wasn't finished]
>
> GREEN GOBLIN: (grunts) It didn't work. **Norman was right. He got it from you.** [stomping on Peter's chest] **That pathetic sickness!**

May raised Peter and was responsible, in part or in whole, for instilling within him his sense of morality. Presumably, Uncle Ben also had a role in that, but he wasn't present, and isn't really talked about in the MCU, so the Goblin almost certainly wasn't referring to him.